# Airflow tasks only available on the first run

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

My use case is simple: I have some processes that interacts with some tables in the database. I want to automate the tables creation, so I added a `create_table_if_not_exists_task`. I only want to run that task in the first DAG run, but not in the following ones, since it's taking DAG time / resources that I could be using somewhere else.

**My question is:** do I have a clean way to do that in Airflow?

The idea I had is to have an Airflow variable updated with that information and check it in the DAG parsing. Don't like it since it creates a connection to the metadata database in each heartbeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ShortCircuitOperator` (or even `BranchPythonOperator` depending on your pipeline) in front of the task you wish to control, access `dag_run` object (either directly or through `context`) in the Python callable, and then check for any previous DagRuns with the `DagRun.get_previous_dagrun()` method.  Something like this (untested though):

```py
def has_previous_dagrun(dag_run):
    return False if dag_run.get_previous_dagrun() is not None else True

...

check_if_first_dagrun = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id="check_if_first_dagrun",
    python_callable=has_previous_dagrun,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create an initialization DAG that run @once

The most idiomatic way to achieve this in my opinion would be to create another DAG to initialize and create your resources with its schedule set at `@once`. It would be run as soon as it is activated and the scheduler is available. You could rerun it manually should you need it someday, and you will know when it was executed. (it feels to me like *Infrastructure as Code*)

```py
with DAG("your_dag_id", schedule="@once", ...) as dag:
    # create GCS Bucket
    create_bucket = GCSCreateBucketOperator(
        task_id="create_bucket",
        bucket_name="your_resource",
        ...
    )
```

You *could* materialize the dependency in your already existing DAG with an [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.3/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task/index.html) but I would advice **against** it. As long as your init DAG has not run you'll have errors, but with automatic retries they will eventually succeed soon.

If your initialization depends on your environment, you'll be able to deploy this in multiple contexts, allowing you to **carry infrastructure and workflow using Airflow DAGs only**.